# Issue with multipart/form-data

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload

I am not able to get values from both files and text input in a servlet when my form includes multipart/form-data. I am using the apache.commons.fileuploads for help with the uploads. Any suggestions. Also in the code below there are some things that I feel should be more efficient. Is there a better way to store these multiple files in a db.

```
public void performTask(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        boolean promo = false;
        Database db = new Database();
        Homepage hp = db.getHomePageContents();

        String part = ParamUtils.getStringParameter(request, "part", "");
        if(part.equals("verbage"))
        {
            String txtcontent = (String)request.getParameter("txtcontent");
            String promoheader = (String)request.getParameter("promoheader");
            String promosubheader = (String)request.getParameter("promosubheader");
            hp.setBodyText(txtcontent);
            hp.setPromoHeader(promoheader);
            hp.setPromoSubHeader(promosubheader);
            System.err.println(txtcontent);
        }
        else
        {

            boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
            if (!isMultipart) 
            {

            }
            else {
                FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
                ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
                List items = null;
                try {
                items = upload.parseRequest(request);
                //System.err.print(items);
                } catch (FileUploadException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Iterator itr = items.iterator();
                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();
                    if(item.getFieldName().equals("mainimg1"))
                    {
                        if(item.getName() !="") hp.setMainImg1(item.getName());
                    }
                    if(item.getFieldName().equals("mainimg2"))
                    {
                        if(item.getName() !="") hp.setMainImg2(item.getName());
                    }
                    if(item.getFieldName().equals("mainimg3"))
                    {
                        if(item.getName() !="") hp.setMainImg3(item.getName());
                    }
                    if(item.getFieldName().equals("promoimg1"))
                    {
                        promo = true;
                        if(item.getName() !="")
                        {
                            hp.setPromoImg1(item.getName());
                            try {
                                File savedFile = new File("/Library/resin-4.0.1/webapps/ROOT/images/promoImg1.jpg");
                                item.write(savedFile);
                                //System.err.print(items);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if(item.getFieldName().equals("promoimg2"))
                    {
                        if(item.getName() !="") 
                        {
                            hp.setPromoImg2(item.getName());
                            try {
                                File savedFile = new File("/Library/resin-4.0.1/webapps/ROOT/images/promoImg2.jpg");
                                item.write(savedFile);
                                //System.err.print(items);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if(item.getFieldName().equals("promoimg3"))
                    {
                        if(item.getName() !="")
                        {
                            hp.setPromoImg3(item.getName());
                            try {
                                File savedFile = new File("/Library/resin-4.0.1/webapps/ROOT/images/promoImg3.jpg");
                                item.write(savedFile);
                                //System.err.print(items);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    }


                    System.err.println("FNAME =" + item.getFieldName() + " : " + item.getName());
                    if (item.isFormField()) {
                    } 
                    else {
                        try {
                            if(!promo)
                            {
                                String itemName = item.getName();
                                File savedFile = new File("/Library/resin-4.0.1/webapps/ROOT/images/"+itemName);
                                item.write(savedFile);
                            }
                            //System.err.print(items);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                          }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        db.updateHomePageContent(hp);
```

Answer (score 10):

When using `multipart/form-data`, the normal input field values are **not** available by `request.getParameter()` because the standard Servlet API prior to version 3.0 doesn't have builtin facilities to parse them. That's exactly why Apache Commons FileUpload exist. You need to check if `FileItem#isFormField()` returns `true` and then gather them from the `FileItem`.

Right now you're ignoring those values in the code. Admittedly, the `FileItem` is a misleading name, if it was me, I'd called it `MultipartItem` or just `Part` representing a part of a `multipart/form-data` body which contains both uploaded fields and normal parameters.

Here's a kickoff example how you should parse a `multipart/form-data` request properly:

```
List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
for (FileItem item : items) {
    if (item.isFormField()) {
        // Process normal fields here.
        System.out.println("Field name: " + item.getFieldName());
        System.out.println("Field value: " + item.getString());
    } else {
        // Process <input type="file"> here.
        System.out.println("Field name: " + item.getFieldName());
        System.out.println("Field value (file name): " + item.getName());
    }            
}
```

Note that you also overlooked a MSIE misbehaviour that it sends the **full** client side path along the file name. You would like to trim it off from the `item.getName()` as per the [FileUpload FAQ](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/faq.html#whole-path-from-IE):

```
String fileName = item.getName();
if (fileName != null) {
    filename = FilenameUtils.getName(filename);
}
```

Comment: I'm using Struts 1.3 and ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request); returns null with a multipart/form-data form (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759688/java-servlet-issue-with-multipart-form-data-form).

Comment: You should use Struts-provided file upload facility. Read its documentation.

Comment: Do you mean the class FormFile? I have a dynamic form coded in json format, so I process the request "by hand".

Comment: @Cricket: I don't do Struts, so I can't go in detail. I only know that it has builtin file upload facility. Note: HTTP requests can be parsed only once. If you get an empty body, then Struts has most likely already implicitly parsed it beforehand. You want probably to turn off it. Again, read its documentation. Otherwise just press "Ask Question" button on right top instead of hijacking someone else's question for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems in the past. The only way i could find round the problem was to put the fileupload into its own form.

Comment: Yeah I need this to be 1 form if possible. I believe it has to be something to do with the servlet cause I can post the values to the url string a nd they look correct but the servlet grabs the value as null