# JSP request.getParameter(string) returns null

Tags: java, forms, jsp

I'm using this  in my index.jsp:

```
<FORM  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="saveFile.jsp" method="POST">
Choose the file To Upload:<br>
<INPUT name="Filename" placeholder="Name to give your file"/>
<INPUT name="File" type="file" accept ="image/jpeg"/>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Send File" />      
</FORM>
```

In saveFile.jsp the String name should get the value from the input field by using request.getParameter("Filename") but the value it returns is null;

```
String name = request.getParameter("Filename");
```

I know the request is send because the file does get delivered to me, but I can't figure out why this part of my code fails.

Comment: please take a look to that post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545717/issue-with-multipart-form-data

Comment: Thank you it gave the answer I was looking for, please send it in as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0):

you have not set any value to the text field

```
<INPUT name="Filename" placeholder="Name to give your file" value="this should come"/>
```

now use

```
String name = request.getParameter("Filename");
```

Comment: Perhaps a value was entered on the webpage?

Comment: Value was entered on the webpage and even copy pasting your <input> into my <form> and your request.getParameter in my saveFile.jsp I get null as a result